# no inbox rules for OWA (Outlook Web App)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

After clicking `Options` in the Microsoft Exchange version of OW in the top right corner I see:

```
Regional Settings
Messaging
Junk E-Mail
Calendar
Out of Office Assistant
Change Password
Accessibility
Mobile Devices
About
```

Where are [inbox rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Inbox-rules-in-Outlook-edea3d17-00c9-434b-b9b7-26ee8d9f5622):

```
At the top of the page, select Settings Settings icon > Options.

In Options, select Organize email > Inbox rules. Or, in Options, under MAIL > Automatic processing, select Inbox rules.
```

Comment: The support page you link indicates the article only applies to Exchange 2016 (the current version being delivered through Office 365). If you're not on this version of Exchange, then this option is probably not available to you.

Comment: Check Default Role assignment policy. Mybaseoptions is enabled? permissions (user roles tab)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using Office 365 or on-prem Exchange, for Office 365:

*Settings* gear icon - *Mail* - under *Automatic processing* click on "Inbox and sweep rules"

Comment: there's no gear icon.  I'm not sure of the version.  Looked around in the app.

Answer (score 0):

1. From the Tools menu (in IE 11 this is the Gear icon in the upper right hand corner of the IE browser) select the "Compatibility View settings" menu item.
2. In the "Compatibility View settings" dialog window, in the "Add this website:" input box, add the domain for your Exchange environment and click the "Add" button.  Then click the "Close" button.
3. Close the IE browser and reopen it.
4. Browse to your Outlook Web Access website.  You should now be able to see all features that have been enabled for Outlook Web Access.
5. If you still don't have all the features that were enabled for use with Outlook Web Access, check your "Compatibility View settings" list and see if it is still populated.
6. Note that if your "Compatibility View settings" list is empty when reopening the IE browser, it is likely that the "Delete browsing history on exit" checkbox is checked on the "General" tab of the "Internet Options" dialog window.  If you want to keep the "Compatibility View Settings" list populated you will need to un-check the "Delete browsing history on exit" checkbox.